# pkg-config not working when compiling an OpenCV program with two objects

Tags: opencv, compilation, linker, g++, pkg-config

I have written an OpenCV program which contains both main.cpp and pedestrian.cpp. I wanted to compile them, so I did the following:

```
g++ -c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags opencv` main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags opencv` pedestrian.cpp -o pedestrian.o
g++ `pkg-config --libs opencv` pedestrian.o main.o -o detect
```

After the third statement, every OpenCV command I use is considered an undefined reference. I have no idea why this is happening since other single object programs work just fine with pkg-config. I checked to see if it was a namespace problem and it wasn't either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the order int the last line to:

```
g++ -o detect pedestrian.o main.o `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

This should work. Order matters when linking the .o files. When the linker finds and unknown OpenCV symbol in any of the .o, it looks for its definition in the following linked elements (i.e. in the elements *to the right*).

Comment: That worked. I had no idea that order matters with the linker. Thanks!